# Global Static Pointer Issue

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, variables, pointers

This is a rather a problem from a convoluted situation. I have a static pointer sitting in one of my header files. Which is being included everywhere, this is why I put it as a static pointer. So that I can quickly initilize it in my main function so that other files can use it.

The problem is this, even after I initialize it and put stuff into it. Other files only find it NULL. It is like every file that includes the header with the static pointer makes a copy of it for itself and even when others initialize it, each file has their own separate copy. Negating ofcourse, the purpose of having a global variable.

How can I cope up with this?. Maybe I am understanding a static variable wrong, or maybe is it  because its a pointer?

Should i be declaring it as: &variable = 5; or just as variable = 5; or &variable = (int)5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It is like every file that includes the header with the static pointer makes a copy of it for itself and even when others initialize it, each file has their own separate copy.

That's what `static` means when applied to a variable at namespace scope:  the variable is given internal linkage, making it "local" to a given translation unit (source file).

If you have a `static` variable at namespace scope in a header file and you include that header file in multiple .cpp files, there will be multiple instances of that variable:  one for each of the .cpp files that include the header file.

If you want a global variable that is shared across multiple source files, you need to make it `extern`.  Declare the variable as extern in the header file, then define the extern variable in exactly one of your .cpp files.

Comment: Your answer along with wilx were exactly what I needed. Thank you sir

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are understanding the `static` keyword wrong. Static keyword at namespace and file scope declares a variable that is only visible inside the translation unit (basically a single .cpp file plus all of its includes) where it is declared. By declaring a static variable in header that you use in multiple .cpp files you are effectively defining multiple variables.

If you want a global pointer then declare it `extern` without `static` in the single header and define it without `extern` or `static` in a single .cpp file. E.g.:

In foo.h:

```
extern int * p;
```

and in main.cpp:

```
int * p = something;
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the global pointer `static` results in the C++ compiler creating a separate pointer for every translation unit, the definition is included in. I'm pretty sure it's not what you want and it's the cause of your problems.

You should declare it `extern` in a header and define once in one cpp file.

I can imagine the confusion came from the way, `static` keyword works inside a `class` or a `struct` definition. Indeed, it works differently there and it creates one variable, common for all instances of the `class` or `struct`.

Btw. In case you actually want a variable to be visible only in one translation unit the recommended way is to put ii into an anonymous namespace. `static` works too, but it's use is discouraged as deprecated.